# Error getting file tree

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FileTree {
    List<File> file_list = new ArrayList<File>();

    public List<File> getTree(String root)
    {
        File f = new File(root);
        ArrayList<File> tmp = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

        for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
        {
            f = tmp.get(i);
            if(f.isFile())
                file_list.add(f);
            else if(f.isDirectory()) 
                getTree(root + "\\" + f.getName());
        }

        return file_list;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
        at FileTree.getTree(FileTree.java:12)
        at FileTree.getTree(FileTree.java:22)
        at Server.main(Server.java:10)
```

I'm trying to get a list of files from a directory (root). The code was working until I tried to access subfoders. What is the problem here?

Comment: This line `getTree(root + "\\" + f.getName());`do a valid path name? Check it

Comment: Stupid mistake I had to use "/". Thanks

Comment: Not a solution but perhaps a simplification: What about having the function take a `File` object. Then check if it is a Directory. If not add it to the list and return, if it is then call it foreach entry in f.listFiles. No need to struggle with pathnames, then.

Answer (score 2):

The method [File#listFiles()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) yields `null` if the file object (f) does not denote a directory (or if an I/O-error occurs).

So before you call `f.listFiles()` you should first check if `f` represents a directory - your input `root` might not be directory. You can use this method: `File#isDirectory()` and then adjust your logic. Or: You have not got granted access privileges for one given subdirectory. In this case you might check readability by using the method `canRead()` (and don't forget to debug `f.getName()` and then to find out if you have enough access rights).

Comment: but I checked if it is a directory before creating the new dir string (root)

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu I have adjusted my answer. Watch also out for hidden subdirectories.

Comment: all was ok exept for "\\", I had to use "/" but thanks for the information given

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu On which OS are you running? Mind that this will be possibly different for Windows and Linux for example.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu, I dont care for windows at the moment

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Maybe you can also use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` for a more OS-independent solution. The char \ should work in Windows (have tested it).

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu "At the moment" means "nah, have future-mihai take care of that". These things will boomerang back to you. If ever possible use OS/Filesystem-independend methods.

Answer (score 0):

Form a [listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) of java.io.File documentation:

> Returns:
>   An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

I see you're checking if file actually is directory, despite first call on root. What might cause your problem then are I/O errors like permission denied for example.
Also the way how you create root path string might cause problems on different file systems, try changing this line

```
getTree(root + "\\" + f.getName());
```

into

```
getTree(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: there is no permission denied because I made all the folders and root works, can an empty folder cause this?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu No, an empty folder will cause `listFiles()` to provide an empty array.